# Display a window through docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-machine, docker-image

I am running a testing program in docker container, which is supposed to pop up a window for showing an image.

I tried difference options such as :

`nvidia-docker run -it  -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw tf_ubuntu_1604:vsl`

However, it shows the error as :

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Pangolin X11: Failed to open X display
Aborted (core dumped)`

which means failing to open a window.

Is there a way to do this task through docker container?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2):

did you try by giving docker the rights to access your x-server??

```
xhost +local:docker
```